# How to solve this "non-finite function value" in R?

Tags: r

I am using R to calculate a nested functions like this:

```
C1_B <- function(T){integrate(function(tau)f(tau),lower=0.01*T,upper=0.99*T)$value}

f <- function(tau) {integrate(function(tau1)sqrt(1/(tau-tau1)),lower=0.01*tau,upper=0.99*tau)$value}

C1_B(0.5)
```

**However, I receive a message like**

> "Error in integrate(function(tau1) sqrt(1/(tau - tau1)), lower = 0.01
>   *  :    non-finite function value
>
> In addition: Warning message:**
>
> In sqrt(1/(tau - tau1)) : NaNs produced"

I guess the problem is about the "(tau-tau1)" in my code; but from the
integral domain I defined ("lower=0.01*tau,upper=0.99*tau"), (tau-tau1) could not be equal to zero.

Could any body please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is `tau - tau1` always positive in your program? If no, that may be one problem since you're passing it to the `sqrt` function.

Comment: What's the use of parameter Z ?

Comment: @Vincent parameter Z is useless here so I delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a try - the problem is that integrate expects the handed over function to be able to deal with input vectors and output a vector of same size.

Luckily the solution is easy - just wrap your function in `sapply`.

The following code works:

```
f <- function(tau) {integrate(function(tau1)sqrt(1/(tau-tau1)),lower=0.01*tau,upper=0.99*tau)$value}

intfun <- function(x) sapply(x,f) 

C1_B <- function(T){integrate(function(tau) intfun(tau),lower=0.01*T,upper=0.99*T)$value}
C1_B(0.5)
```

Comment: glad to help. You can mark the solution so other users with the same problem can quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an exact solution to your integral f. However the value I get does not agree with this numeric approximation. I would say the integral of

```
    d(tau1)/sqrt(tau - tau1)
```

is

```
    -2 * sqrt(tau - tau1)
```

With you upper bound of `0.99*tau` and you lower bound of `0.01*tau` you get

```
    -2 * (sqrt(tau - 0.99 * tau) - sqrt(tau - 0.01 * tau)) = 
    -2 * sqrt(tau) * (sqrt(0.01) - sqrt(0.99))
```

The integration of that for tau can again be solved exactly. It yields

```
    -(4/3)(sqrt(0.01) - sqrt(0.99)) * tau^(3/2)
```

Edit: With your given boundaries `0.01*T` and `0.99*T` the final resulting solution is

```
    -(4/3)(sqrt(0.01)-sqrt(0.99)) * ((0.99 * T)^3/2 - (0.01 * T)^3/2)
```

You can use `integrate` on the first exact integration result (for f). No error are produced. The errors you report are probably due to the method of approximation. Maybe you could try another integration function that uses another approximation. The exact solution of the function f matches the integral calculated in your program.

When you use `integrate` to integrate the exact result for f the results are equal to the exact final solution I gave.

Comment: I fixed a small error in a simplification of the first equation that was present in the first version of my answer and I removed the final equations. In a further edit I added updated final equations and in a last edit I added the information enabling you to check the correctness of the exact results.

Comment: Your solution would be good. But my formula is more complicated than the formula I post here, so it would be not possible for me to derive this kind of exact integration result.
I also try your advice about the approximation method. I use another integration function "integral" in package "pracma". But I also receive a stop message that the domain should be a deterministic number; while my integral domain is varied with "tau".

Comment: Too bad. Couldn't you try to approximate the integrals using upper and lower sums. If you write the approximation yourself you can adjust for the peculiarities of your boundaries i.e. the singularity due to a denominator that can become 0.